# Building the latest version of process as a dependency

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

In order to be able to cancel a process on Windows, I need to make use of [this fix](https://github.com/haskell/process/pull/101) for [`process` package](https://github.com/haskell/process), which is still not released. I've tried adding the latest version from github as a dependency in my `stack.yaml` file:

```
packages:
- '.'
- location:
    git: https://github.com/haskell/process.git
    commit: 2fb7e739771f4a899a12b45f8b392e4874616b89
  extra-dep: true
```

But the `stack build` command fails:

```
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Logs have been written to: C:\Users\nadalesagutde\Documents\github\capitanbatata\sandbox\racing-turtles\.stack-work\logs\process-1.6.1.0.log

Configuring process-1.6.1.0...
Warning: The 'build-type' is 'Configure' but there is no 'configure' script.
You probably need to run 'autoreconf -i' to generate it.
setup.exe: configure script not found.
```

In the README of `process` is stated that `autoreconf -i` must be run before, but I don't know how to tell this to `stack`. Do I need some extra configuration in my `stack.yaml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the package's git repo does not include the "configure" script, which is needed to use the package directly.  The reason things work when downloading from hackage is that the source distribution does include the configure script.  Frustrating!  I think this is an atypical design decision for a package that uses configure.  I've opened this stack issue: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3534

Suggested workaround is to clone the repo as a submodule and run `autoreconf -i` manually.